# Set equivalent size to div with jss

Tags: jquery, css, jscript

I have two div with id respectively firstCard & resultCard.

```
var newHeight = document.querySelector('#resultCard').clientHeight;
document.querySelector('#firstCard').style.height = newHeight;

alert(document.querySelector('#resultCard').clientHeight);
alert(document.querySelector('#firstCard').clientHeight);
```

I'd like to adjust the firstCard height to be equal to resultCard. What i tried doesn't work, my alert indicates two different values (432 for resultCard & 400 for firstCard).

Is there something i'm missing ?

EDIT : was missing = newHeight + "px";
Also had to set height: auto in my css.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
document.querySelector('#firstCard').style.height = newHeight + "px";
```